# Is there any Stack Exchange site to request websites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for a Stack Exchange site to request a certain webservice. For example:

*I am looking for a Website to watch past (full) football matches in the Irish League. I cannot find any by Google. Does anybody know such a site?*

Where would such a request be appropriate?

Comment: You might request a dump of deleted spam posts. They get loads of it and live streaming of football seems to be a thing spammers advertise for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's an appropriate Stack Exchange site for this question.

It's certainly [**off-topic** at *Web Applications*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

[*Software Recommendations*](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) accepts recommendation requests for [web *apps*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps), but [not web *sites*](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/219/156). This would seem to be more of the latter.